# navigator.MaxTouchPoints returns 2 on Edge browser on windows laptop even though it is not a touch device

Tags: touch, microsoft-edge

Edge browser returns 2 for navigator.MaxTouchPoints. We use the property to detect a touch device. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure whether you are using MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser or MS Edge chromium browser. You also did not mention the version of the browser.

I tested with both browsers and based on my testing I found that navigator.MaxTouchPoints returns 0.

Test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
alert("navigator.maxTouchPoints = " + navigator.maxTouchPoints);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

If you are using an older version then I suggest update it with the latest version and again make a test.

If the issue persists then try to provide the detailed information with snapshots may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Most probably I am on an older version. This is the version I am on: Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0. When I run the snippet it returns 2. Which version are you on?

Comment: I am using MS Edge 44.18362.1.0 I can see that your version is not too older. I have a doubt that this issue can be related to the laptop you are using. I suggest you try to run the code on another machine to see the result. It can help you to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this behaviour. It is caused when a laptop has a multi-touch capable touchpad. There was even a [microsoft issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/20417074/) for this (however has been removed)

If I run the following [test](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/pointer-multitouch-detect.html) from my edge (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and HTML 18.18362) all values are green (which is invalid).

[image]
There are some [proposed fixes here](https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/issues/967).

**Update:**

Unfortunatly the first test from the patrickhlauke testpage with a real touchscreen and the old edge revealed the following:

"Touch feature detect" => all red Which is plain wrong.
However the navigator.maxTouchPoints are different:

```
navigator.maxTouchPoints (real touchdisplay) = 10 
navigator.maxTouchPoints (Touchpad) = 2
```

So I will do something like this:

```
if(Browser=edge && maxTouchPoints > 2) => real Touchdisplay
if(Browser == edge && maxTouchPoints <=2) only tochpad not real touch display
```

=> After 2021-03-09 when the old edge is EOL'd I will remove that code...